# pass variable into Azure DevOps Release pipeline from github actions trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to trigger the release pipeline in the ADO from the GitHub actions. While triggering I am passing some variables to the release pipeline but the variables are not assigning to the pipeline.

the below command i am using in the Git Actions

```
  - name: Azure Pipelines Action
    uses: Azure/pipelines@v1
    with:
        azure-devops-project-url: https://dev.azure.com/XXXXX
        azure-pipeline-name: 'XXXXX'
        azure-devops-token: ${{ XXXX }}
        azure-pipeline-variables:  '{"regionCode": "DL"}'
```

in the Release pipeline i was giving -regionCode $(regionCode)  in the arguments section to fetch the variable value

Answer (score 0):

They are most likely **runtime** variables, not pipeline parameters. They would be accessed in YAML using the runtime variable syntax, `$[variables['regionCode']]`, not the parameter syntax `${{ parameters['regionCode']}}` or compile-time variable syntax `${{variables['regionCode']}}`

Comment: that doesnt work for me when i try to echo the variable in devops its blank